# ARMA/GARCH statistical significance of estimated parameters

Tags: statistical-significance, arima, garch, misspecification

My question is general and is concerned with ARMA-GARCH modeling.

When performing the joint estimation of the ARMA and GARCH parts, some works tend to not be concerned with the statistical significance of the parameter estimates of the conditional mean equation.

If the conditional mean equation is something very simple, like, e.g., a constant this make some sense. But what if the equation contains AR and/or MA terms? Doesn't it mean that the ARMA-GARCH model is misspecified?

Is there any specific reason behind that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lack of statistical significance of a model's coefficients is not a strong indication of misspecification. (This could be contrasted to, say, systematic patterns in the model's residuals.) It simply indicates the sample size is too small to reliably distinguish the true coefficients from zero. You do not prove the coefficients are truly equal zero, you simply fail to reject such a null hypothesis. (For a given significance level, failing to reject a hypothesis is not as convincing as rejecting the "opposite" hypothesis would be.)

Statistical significance of individual coefficients is also a poor guide in model selection, especially in the context of forecasting where ARMA-GARCH models are routinely used, as argued by Rob J. Hyndman in ["Statistical tests for variable selection"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tests2/).

Comment: thank you very much for sharing your knowledge. Just one more thing. Concerning the lag selection procedure. Since we talk about ARMA-GARCH processes is it better to jointly fit such a model starting from a standard model, e.g., AR(1)-GARCH(1,1),  and then tweak - if needed - the lag order of ARMA and/or GARCH parts in order to get a model that passes all the diagnostic tests? Or to initially select an appropriate ARMA model based on ACF/PACF (I am a little worried about the Ljung-Box distribution in such a case) and then perform an ARCH test and then move to GARCH area. Again, joint est

Comment: @peter5, I wish I had a simple, universal answer to the question. I guess I would work with joint ARMA-GARCH models all the way if possible, since ignoring either ARMA or GARCH may mess up the diagnostics of the other (like the null distribution of the Ljung-Box test that you mention). But I am not 100% confident in my advice.

Comment: I share your point of view. As far I know, this is a very complicated matter due to many reasons. However, the joint procedure sounds correct, from the statistical point of view. Thank you very much for sharing your precious time and knowledge.

Comment: @peter5, you are welcome! I appreciate your gratitude.